# Символьный массив указателей в структуре

Tags: c, структуры

Начал изучать структуры 
Хочу записать вот это правильно, чтобы компилятор не ругался

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
struct selfish
{
    char city[30];
};
struct Man 
{
    char *fio[60];
    int year;
    int month;
    struct selfish;
};

int main()
{
    struct Man myself;
    gets_s(myself.fio);
    puts(myself.fio);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73958/discussion-on-question-by-elvin-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе нужен массив символов, а не массив указателей.

> ```
> char *fio[60];
> ```

```
char fio[60];
```

А ещё тут что-то не то:

> ```
> struct selfish;
> ```

либо ты забыл написать имя поля, либо это вообще надо удалить.

Comment: а массив указателей не будет себя вести так же, как и двумерный массив?

Comment: нет, чтобы он стал двумерным, надо ещё память выделить.

Comment: Вопрос еще один появился: как такая конструкция называется struct Man 
{
    char *fio[60];
    int year;
    int month;
    struct selfish;
}  структура в структуре ? и почему нужно еще для внутренней дописывать поле  struct selfish bd;

Answer (score 0):

> Начал изучать структуры

А что там изучать-то?

Любой шкаф в твоём доме - это структура:

```
Шкаф {
    нижняя полка, называется bottom;
    средняя полка, называется middle;
    верхняя полка, называется top;
};
```

Каждая из полок тоже может являться структурой, содержащей другие структуры :) Например, на каждой из них может храниться коробка, содержащая ящички для мелочи. А в ящичках этих можно хранить неделимые элементы. Например, что-то одно (`year`, `month`), или несколько однотипных саморезов (`char fio[]`).